# Pandas does not recognize global dataframe in a function

Tags: pandas

I have a method where I am trying to append one dataframe to anotehr, one of the dataframes need to be accessible outside the method.

```
def method1():
    global df_0;
    df_1=pd.read_excel(filepath)
    df_0=df_0.append(df_1)

method1()
```

I get:

```
df_0 is not defined
```

Comment: why don't you send global df in function as a parameter ?

Comment: In the code you've posted you're never initialising `df_0` so it makes sense that it's not defined.